# How to set user assigned identity with Azure Powershell (not az cli)?

Tags: azure, powershell

I am trying to set user assigned identities to a azure web app via the [Az Powershell module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/new-azureps-module-az?view=azps-5.8.0)

Here is my attempt with Set-AzResource which **does not** work

```ps
$webApp = Get-AzWebApp -Name "somewebapp" -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName

$site = Get-AzResource -Id $webApp.Id

$appIdentity = Get-AzUserAssignedIdentity -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Name "someid"
$appIdentity2 = Get-AzUserAssignedIdentity -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Name "someotherid"

$site.Identity.Type = "UserAssigned"
$site.Identity.UserAssignedIdentities = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[System.String,Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Models.IdentityUserAssignedIdentitiesValue]"
$site.Identity.UserAssignedIdentities[$appIdentity.Id] = New-Object "Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Models.IdentityUserAssignedIdentitiesValue" -ArgumentList $appIdentity.ClientId, $appIdentity.PrincipalId
$site.Identity.UserAssignedIdentities[$appIdentity2.Id] = New-Object "Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Models.IdentityUserAssignedIdentitiesValue" -ArgumentList $appIdentity2.ClientId, $appIdentity2.PrincipalId

$site | Set-AzResource -Force
```

The problem from what I can see is that `Set-AzResource` only sends in the body of the HTTP request the "properties" property, ignoring the "identity" property:

```json
{
  "properties": {
    "name": "somewebapp",
    "state": "Running",
    ...
  }
}
```

How can I set user assigned identities on a web app via the Az powershell module? [Set-AzWebApp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.websites/set-azwebapp?view=azps-5.8.0) doesn't have any parameters for this either (the `-AssignIdentity` param is for system assigned identity).

For reference, doing this with the azure cli **does** work:

```ps
az webapp identity assign --resource-group "rg-someresourcegroup" --name "somewebapp" --identities @($appIdentity.Id, $appIdentity2.Id)
```

Edit: I found [this issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/13109) which seems to confirm my suspicion that this is indeed not supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-managed-identity?tabs=dotnet#using-azure-powershell-1) shows, the current version of the Azure PowerShell commandlets for Azure App Service **do not support** user-assigned identities.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That does confirm that it's indeed not possible yet via the Azure PowerShell commandlets.